# ImageButton and Input type="image" border only appearing on hover

Tags: html, css, imagebutton

When you hover over an `input type='image'` the border appears, and then disappears on leaving the image. But not just the visibility, its spacing is lost too. I want my image to remain in a static position but still benefit from the border appearing. Hence I only want it to change colour. Is it possible to make the border appear before hovering? It's the image bobbing about I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a border width on the image, but no colour, and then set colour on hover. This will ensure there is always a fixed width border around the image, and therefore won't shift the image position on hover.

```
input[type="image"]
{
   border:solid 3px transparent;
}

input[type="image"]:hover
{
   border-color:#ff0;
}
```

***Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/rAPds/*

Comment: I tried so many permutations. But you nailed the one that works. Note that had to remove periods(.)

Comment: Could I trouble you again by asking if you know how to get rid of the space between imagebuttons. I set 
.input[type="image"]
{
   border:solid 3px transparent;  
   margin: 0 !important;
}
...but it didn't fix it.

Comment: @DavidStewart The space is there because of the transparent border. If you remove this border you will have the issue of images jumping when the border is applied on hover again. One solution would be to nest each input in a div container and use Chris Coyier's solution http://css-tricks.com/image-rollover-borders-that-do-not-change-layout/

Comment: I thought that at first. But this is definitely an extra space which is not account for when I look in the "view source". I can put my mouse pointer between the two imagebuttons and highlight neither

Comment: I have figured the second one out...it seems to be a line feed issue. I just needed to have the buttons follow from one to the next in the html without a line break. Thanks for help with the hover. Page looks Sweet!

Comment: @DavidStewart No problem, happy to help, glad you got it sorted!